# React Dropdown: Still getting 'unique key prop' warning after adding unique keys

Tags: reactjs, dropdown, html-select

Generating a `<select><option>` dropdown (DD) from an array of objects. Added an id property to the objects to supposedly fix the dreaded "Each child in a list should have a unique 'key' prop" warning.

Sample data:

{id:70, city:"Allentown", state:"Pennsylvania"},
{id:71, city:"Alliance", state:"Ohio"}, 
{id:72, city:"Alliance", state:"Nebraska"},

Sample code:

```
<select name="cities" id="cities" onClick={selectCity}>  
  {cities.map((x) => (<option key={x.id} value={x.city}>{x.city}</option>))}
</select>
```

Note: The DD, and the array that populates it, is initially empty when the component loads. It's populated by a click event in another DD.

Spent a goodly chunk o' time trying out several SO suggestions. Tried wrapping the `<select>` in a `<React.Fragment>` block, and added a key to that. Tried using both 70 and '70' for the id property. Warning still appears. Using the array index as the key eliminates the warning, but I can't use that method because of other problems it causes.

Questions:
-- Data is coming from a JS file that I'm importing, is that a factor?
-- Is the array initially being empty on component load causing this?
-- What's the proper way to add the key prop to avoid the warning?

Thanks ahead of time for any help you awesome SO people can provide!

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question. In the initial post I asked "Is the array initially being empty on component load causing this?" The answer is yes, the empty array produces the warning.
When the component first loads, in map() it looks for a valid value for [array element].id. At this point, the array is empty, and has no ids loaded. It normally remains empty until an onClick event loads it with values. Had to add an initial default value to avoid the 'unique keys' warning. The fix is:

BAD (produces unique key warning):
`const [cities, setCities] = useState([]);`

GOOD (no warning): `const [cities, setCities] = useState([{id: 0, city: '', state: ""}]);`